# jquery date picker and thickbox collation

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Im using the jsDatePick.min.1.3.js type of Datepicker in my page. It works fine in normal page. But within the thickbox the datepicker calender is not dispalyed in my onclick event. Please give your suggestion to fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably - as you have not provided your code - you have to register the onclick event *after* you opened the thickbox, because the content itself is only present after the thickbox initialize.

But as i said - provide the relevant code-pages to help us helping you.

Comment: My code within the thickbox includes the jquery datepicker and css file as,

Please refer the URL `http://pastebin.com/TXAvKVSC`

When i run this page, as a php file(not as a thickbox), the datepicker works well while clicking the text field. But when i call this page as thickbox, i cant get the datepicker. Please give any suggestion to fix this issue. Thanks.